# I want the div to always appear under the input box

Tags: php, html, css

I want them to appear under the input box even if the the browser restore down or resized.

I tried the position code on css. but it doesnt work.

here's my code:

```
$data .= '<input type="text"  value="">';
$data .= '<input type="button" id="btndotdot" class="btndotdot" value="...">'; ?>

<div class="popupmenu_set pop_prjctcode" id="popupmenu343" style=" position:sticky; left: 428px; top: 144px; width: 173px; cursor: pointer; margin: 0; overflow: auto; padding: 0; display: block; "> 
    <div class="pop_body" id="scrollx" style="position: sticky; "> 
         <ul id="list" name="list" >
            <?php  while($rs1=mysql_fetch_array($que)): ?>
             <li  data-value=<?php echo $rs1['ProjectCode']; ?> class="pop_opt1" method="POST" style="font-size: 12px;"><a><?php echo $rs1['ProjectCode'].' - '.$rs1['ProjectName'];?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
         </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="exit popupmenu_xonhover"> 
         <img src="exit.png">Exit
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us your CSS too please ? Also, try to explain WHY it's not working, or what is not right, will make answering easier!

Comment: same with the style inside the div

Comment: share an image of your current view and your desired view

Comment: remove position sticky or understand how to use it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

Do u mean to display div in next line ? If yes, Try with `<br>` after input tag